# "jpeglib.h: No such file or directory" ghostscript port in OPENBSD

Tags: gcc, jpeg, ports, openbsd

Hello I have a problem with compiling a ghostscript from ports in openbsd 4.7.

SO i have jpeg-7 installed, I have latest port tree for obsd4.7.

```
===>  Building for ghostscript-8.63p11
mkdir -p /usr/ports/pobj/ghostscript-8.63p11/ghostscript-8.63/obj
gmake LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib -shared' GS_XE=./obj/../obj/libgs.so.11.0 STDIO_IMPLEMENTATION=c DISPLAY_DEV=./obj/../obj/display.dev BINDIR=./obj/../obj GLGENDIR=./obj/../obj GLOBJDIR=./obj/../obj PSGENDIR=./obj/../obj PSOBJDIR=./obj/../obj CFLAGS='-O2 -fno-reorder-blocks -fno-reorder-functions -fomit-frame-pointer -march=i386 -fPIC -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-builtin -fno-common -DGS_DEVS_SHARED -DGS_DEVS_SHARED_DIR=\"/usr/local/lib/ghostscript/8.63\"' prefix=/usr/local ./obj/../obj/gsc 
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/usr/ports/pobj/ghostscript-8.63p11/ghostscript-8.63'
cc -I./obj/../obj -I./src   -DHAVE_MKSTEMP -O2 -fno-reorder-blocks -fno-reorder-functions -fomit-frame-pointer -march=i386 -fPIC -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-builtin -fno-common -DGS_DEVS_SHARED -DGS_DEVS_SHARED_DIR=\"/usr/local/lib/ghostscript/8.63\" -DGX_COLOR_INDEX_TYPE='unsigned long long' -o ./obj/../obj/sdctc.o -c ./src/sdctc.c
In file included from src/sdctc.c:17:
obj/jpeglib_.h:1:21: jpeglib.h: No such file or directory
In file included from src/sdctc.c:19:
src/sdct.h:58: error: field `err' has incomplete type
src/sdct.h:70: error: field `err' has incomplete type
src/sdct.h:72: error: field `cinfo' has incomplete type
src/sdct.h:73: error: field `destination' has incomplete type
src/sdct.h:84: error: field `err' has incomplete type
src/sdct.h:87: error: field `dinfo' has incomplete type
src/sdct.h:88: error: field `source' has incomplete type
gmake[1]: *** [obj/../obj/sdctc.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/ports/pobj/ghostscript-8.63p11/ghostscript-8.63'
gmake: *** [so] Error 2
*** Error code 2

Stop in /usr/ports/print/ghostscript/gnu (line 2225 of /usr/ports/infrastructure/mk/bsd.port.mk).
```

I tried to place one more param in CFLAGS in Makefile with value "-I/usr/local" but no luck =(
People in irc [freenode server, #openbsd channel] refuses give any help for ports at all, and even more - because this is 4.7 unstable version.

I have my reasons to use this version and ports believe me =)

```
CFLAGS+=        -DSYS_TYPES_HAS_STDINT_TYPES    \   
                -I${LOCALBASE}/include          \
                -I${LOCALBASE}/include/ijs      \
                -I${LOCALBASE}/include/libpng   \
```

Comment: Have you considered asking the OpenBSD mailing list or getting on the SILC channel?

Comment: Earlz: they pretty stubborned.. =( They really very *BAD WORD* about compilation issues.. I tried to write to that mailing list, now I have two ideas what's wrong. 1) userland and port tree release mixed, i mean port is -STABLE and userland  is -RELEASE , this can be an issue.. I need to recompile whole userland from -STABLE CVS repo. 2) something wrong with CFLAGS, but now as how that port maintener thinks. he really thinks that I'm an idiot and that my $CFLASG /etc/mk.conf breaks this port, althoug whem you type make, the makefile appends current CFLAGS to the cflags which are in Makefile.

Comment: so your putting in custom CFLAGS? I wouldn't recommend that. And yea, it is a hostile community, at best. I would get userland up to -STABLE though. It's completely unsupported to use a mixed system and may be the cause of your problems.

Comment: yeap after upgrading userland to -STABLE it's ok now. and yes I have mk.conf costume flags for memory optimisation =) and now it works :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok nevermind, I just recompiled whole userland and now it's ok=)

Answer (score 0):

You can find where jpeglib.h is by using `find`:

```
find / -name jpeglib.h
```

Once you know the path it's in, you can add the correct `-I` flag.

Comment: or use the (much more handy) `locate jpeglib.h`. you'll also probably have to add a `-L` flag.

Comment: yes I tried this already:

# locate jpeglib.h
/usr/local/include/jpeglib.h
/usr/ports/pobj/ghostscript-8.63p11/ghostscript-8.63/jasper/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_jpeglib.h
/usr/ports/pobj/jpeg-7/jpeg-7/jpeglib.h

jpeglib.h lies in the /usr/local/include/ =)